# Why does copy constructor call other class' default constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I was wondering why an error like this would occur.

```
no matching function for call to 'Foo::Foo()'
```

in code for a copy constructor? Assume Foo is just an object with normal fields ( no dynamically allocated memory, etc. ), and the only constructor it has defined is a constructor that takes one argument.

I didn't even know the constructor needed to be considered though. If the code says something like

```
bar = thing.bar; //
```

and bar is of Foo type, with the specifications described above, shouldn't it just generate a shallow copy and be done with it? Why does a default constructor need to be invoked?

Comment: Show us your code. Have you defined the default constructor?

Comment: It will compile if you add an empty Foo::Foo()'s definition. But what makes me wonder is why do u try to call it anyway, in the copy constructor? Can you show us code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't define a constructor, the compiler will generate a default constructor, however if you *do* define a constructor (Like a copy constructor) the compiler *won't* generate the default constructor, so you need to define that constructor too.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the compiler only wouldn't define the default constructor if I defined a default constructor, not just any constructor.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you've defined the copy constructor without defining any other constructor.

Once you declare an constructor explicitly, the compiler no longer provides a default constructor for you.  Consequently, you no longer have a mechanism to construct an object of the class in the first place (and therefore wouldn't be able to copy it).

Answer (score 1):

If, as you say, you're doing "something like

```
bar = thing.bar;
```

it's presumably in the **body** of your class's copy ctor -- so the `bar` field gets initialized with its class's default ctor first, then uses that class's assignment operator for this statement.  If `bar`'s class only has a copy ctor, no default ctor, you'll need to add a `bar(thing.bar)` clause **before** your class's copy ctor opening `{` and remove that assignment (generally a good idea anyway, but mandatory under the "no default ctor" condition).